# How can i find out a value of html variable with selenium

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

Im trying to find out the value of a progress of a video with selenium. I know i need to find out a way with java script executor but didnt find out yet how.

this is the element :

```
<div aria-label="scrub bar" aria-level="polite" 
     aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" class="scrubBar" 
     role="slider" tabindex="0" aria-valuenow="100%" aria-valuetext="100%%">

    <vg-scrub-bar-current-time _ngcontent-c27="">
       <div class="background" style="width: 100%;"></div><!---->
    </vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
    <vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time _ngcontent-c27="">
       <div class="background" style="width: 100%;"></div>
    </vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time>      
 </div>
```

valuenow="100% is what i want to monitor (i want to know when it reaches 100% to trigger another action).

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to locate this element `<div aria-label="scrub bar" aria-level="polite" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" class="scrubBar" role="slider" tabindex="0" aria-valuenow="100%" aria-valuetext="100%%">` ?

Comment: `document.getElementBy<YourLocator>("pathToElement").getAttribute("aria-valuenow");` gives you a value of attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript code:

```
String value = (String) js.executeScript("return document.getElementByXpath(\"//*[@id=\"cdk- accordion-child-15\"]/div/app-sensors-video/app-cognata-video/vg- player/vg-scrub-bar/div).getAttribute(\"aria-valuenow\")");
```

gives you a value of `aria-valuenow`.

UPDATE:

Java code:

```
// elem is WebElement
elem.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cdk- accordion-child-15']/div/app-sensors-video/app-cognata-video/vg- player/vg-scrub-bar/div"));

String s = (String) elem.getAttribute("aria-valuenow");
```

Comment: So finally my line should look like this?  

    String value = (String) 
    js.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath(\"//*[@id=\"cdk- 
   accordion-child-15\"]/div/app-sensors-video/app-cognata-video/vg- 
   player/vg-scrub-bar/div").getAttribute("aria-valuenow"));

Comment: @Udi I cant prove if `xPath` is correct. Other stuff is ok

Comment: yes i know :)  
xpath is ok but im getting an error under the getAttribute    

The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: @Udi I have updated my answer with Java code, try it

Comment: @Udi after some research I have found probably a solution for your issue with `js.executeScript...`. I have edited an answer

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to find it using JavaScriptExecutor neither an expert with Java. Having said that, given the information, I will wait for that element as shown below and once found break out of the loop and initiate another action

This is not the answer you were looking for but if may or may not help you to come up with a solution

Convert to Java Syntax

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[aria-label="scrub bar"][aria-valuenow="100%"]')
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

I like the answer given by Andrei Suvorkov,

```
 while True:
        percentage = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[aria-label="scrub bar"]').get_attribute('aria-valuenow')
        if percentage == '100%':
            break
```